# Html2canvas not allowing to capture my image from CDN

Tags: html2canvas

I'm trying to get screenshot using html2canvas. It's working fine for text but it is not rendering CDN images, if i host the images in server it was working fine but if trying to load images from CDN links those image were not rendering.

```
<script>
    function downloadScreenshot() {
        var certificateContent = document.getElementById('certificateContent');

        html2canvas(certificateContent).then(canvas => {
            var dataUrl = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = dataUrl;
            link.download = 'QR.png';
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        });
    }
</script>
```

Help me to solve this issue

Comment: You need to use a proxy server to get those images getting loaded => https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/proxy/.